# Is signing a permanent contract celebrated/ announced - UK

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, privacy

**The scenario:**

I've been working  on a temporary 6 month contract with my company and I have just agreed to new terms which will give me a permanent **full employee** contract.

**The question:**

Is it normal in the UK to announce this to colleagues to receive congratulations and make *a big deal* out of it or is it just something that I keep private and only reveal if asked about?

Comment: Can someone explain the down votes? I'm new to this Stack. Whilst I understand I'm probably doing something wrong, it's not good form to down vote and not explain.

Comment: Not the down voter, but people probably think this is not something we can answer as it may depend on your specific company culture. Such things are best asked to your colleagues or to your manager.

Comment: It would be helpful if they left a comment to explain the downvote, but I suspect it's because there's no black and white answer unfortunately!

Comment: I think you aren't doing anything wrong. Don't worry about the downvotes, people vote for all sorts of reasons. Welcome to the Workplace!

Comment: @RobE Welcome to StackExchange: The land of drive by down votes.  Dont think much of it, as it happens all the time, on all the sites.  I suspect many of the people dont even read the post when voting down.

Comment: You have 8 votes, with 2 being down.  That's pretty good really.

Comment: @MisterPositive That's quite typical of your username! ;-) But i wrote that when I had 0 upvotes and 2 downvotes.

Comment: @Keltari, well that's a bit of a generalization... For instance, on Ask Ubuntu it happens very rarely.

Comment: @RobE  For the purposes of clarification, can you confirm whether this change makes you a full employee or whether your contract has been extended indefinitely?  The way I see it from your wording, your contract is now notionally unending.

Comment: @Snow full employee. (includes health care etc..)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It really depends on the company culture, policies and how well you get on with your colleagues.

In my experience, smaller companies and start-ups are more likely to 'announce' it (although is usually via email) but, if you get on with your colleagues, then you'll probably have shared that information already? Larger companies tend not to make a fuss. You might find your immediate manager will welcome you again and let your immediate team know.

If you want to keep it private, then you're well within your right to ask them not to announce it.

Comment: Actually in the UK you don't normally celebrate or mention this at all

Comment: I'm in the UK and that's not been my experience. Having gone from permanent to contracting to permanent again (all the same company), an announcement was always made to the team of 50+ people because that's how the company culture was.

Comment: Don't confuse "permanent contract", with "full employee".  I guess that's what some people are doing with this question.

Comment: Every company I worked for in the UK, the team manager announced the change and there was a little celebration amongst fellow colleagues. So it really does depend on the company @Neuromancer

Comment: I celebrated but that was after 20 years of short term contracts

Comment: After redundancy, I joined a temp agency and got a 6-week placement with a UK government department. At the end of that, they asked to keep me for 6 months. Then I was offered a 1-year fixed term contract as a direct employee. This was renewed 4 times. At the 2-year stage they advertise your role and you have to apply for it and be interviewed ("fair and open competition"). After 4 years total they must terminate you or make you permanent. They did the latter. At every stage, my success was announced to the whole office and everybody clapped. I was expected to bring cakes.

Answer (score 8):

You're still on a contract.  The only thing that's really changed is the end date.

So, there's no need to really formally announce it or celebrate.  Transitioning to be a full employee might be announced, but this depends on the company/manager.

Regardless, it seems appropriate to celebrate your change in status with cakes for the team (unless you especially want to be secretive about things).

Comment: I like the cake idea, as we have a strong cake culture at this company funnily enough.

Comment: Everyone likes cake.

Comment: @Snow - I have no idea what you mean about the difference between "permanent contract" and "full employee" within UK employment. "Permanent contract" isn't a standard phrase, and the only way I can parse it is "signing an employment contract to become a permanent employee", i.e. becoming a "full employee". Could you clarify what you think the difference is? I googled "permanent contract vs employee UK" and the hits were about permanent vs employee.

Comment: A permanent contract (as I see it) is a contractor with no fixed term, but in all other ways is the same.  Benefits between a permanent contractor and a full time employee would be completely different.  The UK law on this is [here](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/renewing-or-ending-a-fixedterm-contract).  Although the maximum term is 4 years, I know of cases where contractors have extended indefinitely at the same company in the same role with no difficulty.

Comment: The link in your previous comment is to a page on fixed-term contracts, which doesn't really help to clarify the difference between permanent contractors (which sounds like a combination which HMRC's IR35 would make pretty rare) and permanent employees. In addition, I find it hard to read the question's reference to "*a temporary 6 month contract with my company*" as plausibly written by a contractor.

Comment: I concur with Peter Taylor. Snow, you talk of contractors "extending indefinitely" with no difficulty; you extend a fixed term contract, not a permanent one. As a UK contractor, I have never heard of any non-fixed term contract other than a full employment contract. I think this is clearly a case of someone becoming a full employee after a probationary period.

Comment: @Quirk My thinking here appears to be backed up by the OP in his comment [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/112808/is-signing-a-permanent-contract-celebrated-announced-uk/112816?noredirect=1#comment350779_112818).  I'm sorry that whatever terminology I'm using is confusing, I didn't mean it to be. Let's see of the OP can clarify this.

Comment: This is my misunderstanding, based on the original wording of the question and my own experience of long-term contractors.  My bad.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend against announcing it, without clearance from management, as you could be unaware of other things that are going on. An example, it could be that you are actually being hired to replace someone who is being made redundant, or something along those lines. You announcing it could actually put you in hot water if it reveals too much information to the wrong parties.

If you want to announce it, I would recommend clearing it with management first, or only doing so with very close friends that are aware they shouldn't be discussing these changes with other people until an official statement is made.

Apart from that, the rest depends on culture and you should refer to [the other answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/112809/52713) about that as they cover it all really well.

Comment: Unless the six month contract was simply a probational period.  You might not want to hire a permanent contractor without knowing they're able to do the job and fits well into the team.

Comment: @Snow what you mentioned is/was more or less the case.

Comment: @RobE It's still possible your hiring could have implications on other employees, you may not be aware of the full situation. I'm merely suggesting that you tread with care as small things can have grand consequences

Comment: Or it's just a simple budgeting thing. The company I work for has plenty of permanent contractor - it's not a big issue.  Rob probably knows his situation better than anyone else does.

Comment: @Draken I agree that it could still have implications, and that your answer is worth while to consider for any others that find themselves in a similar situation. Even though I believe it's not the case in this situation.

Comment: if you are being hired to replace somebody being made redundant run, as that is illegal in the UK

Comment: @WendyG There are grey areas to the law, *["One potential grey area within redundancy law is when you are genuinely cutting down your workforce but you make one member of staff redundant and place an existing employee into their role. This is generally deemed to be acceptable as long as you have reduced the overall size of the workforce and you can prove there is a genuine need for doing so"](http://www.redundancyexpert.co.uk/can-i-take-more-staff-after-making-people-redundant.html)*

Comment: Other choices are, 3 contractors hired to do job, end of contract keeping only one and other 2 are being let go. Shouting that you got the job when management haven't had chance to review with other potential applicants would be considered bad form

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not depend on the company culture, location etc..

It is entirely up to you. You might wish to tell your immediate team as you may be able to gain access to other company resources that are only available to permanent employees.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you are really excited about, tell whoever you want. Being down to earth is never frowned upon, just don't be rude.